# Changing the domain I use for hosting static resources effect my main site?

Tags: seo

Hello I'm curious to know would changing the domain i use for hosting static resources effect my main site.

I currently have my main site: www.mydomain.com

Images are hosted on a subdomain: images.mydomain.com

I will setup a new domain: static-mydomain.com where I will host all static resources including the images.

Setup 301 redirects from images.mydomain > static-mydomain.com

Will this hurt my domain www.mydomain.com?

Answer (score 1):

> Will this hurt my domain www.mydomain.com?

No, shouldn't. But be careful and don't produce some millions of 404-images. And think about making this domain cookie-free. In general Google is familiarized with hosting static assets elsewhere.

What i personally don't understand - why this step? What is not OK with static subdomain?

Comment: Thank you Evgeniy. For the current subdomain I have already set cookies on the top-level domain so all my requests to the subdomain will include those cookies. I just want to reduce the size of the http requests, so ill be making this new domain cookie-free